# Performance gain with Grunt or Gulp?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I have use grunt and set it up with doing my checking for jQuery / javascript, it did seem easy to use but something I have been seen around is gulp and a many plugins moving over to using this over grunt?

I can not really see any difference in the two? I know the Grunt have a lot of plugins listed and can do lots more, than what I do with it.

So why would you use Gulp over Grunt? Is is better, faster, more plugins? Or is this just personal option on what is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a preferential difference between the way the libraries are architected.

Grunt passes around Objects ({}) so it's more "code by configuration". Gulp utilizes streams so it's more "code over configuration". Very good presentation on it here:

http://markdalgleish.github.io/presentation-build-wars-gulp-vs-grunt/

Basically it's not a "performance" issue so much as a preference issue. If you have things working in one, there's not a large need to switch.

(As of writing this 2014-03, Grunt is more established in the marketplace so you will have more support/libraries going that route)

EDIT 2016-06: The gulp community/package marketplace has grown. Gulp keeps files as streams in memory and passes them into transform functions/steps from there. Grunt writes things to the filesystem after each step and then picks them up from the filesystem in the next step. Good long form explanation [here](http://jaysoo.ca/2014/01/27/gruntjs-vs-gulpjs/). To my knowledge Grunt doesn't support streaming between tasks yet as mentioned.

Comment: good answer - I will have a look at the link you posted for me.

Comment: thanks for good answer